# Fourier Series of a Function discontinuous in one point

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I had to calculate the Fourier Series $\left(\displaystyle{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}}c_n\,e^{i\,n\,t}\right)$ of

$g(t)= \begin{cases}\sinh(t),&-\pi<t<\pi \\\\ 0, &t=\pi\end{cases}$

Just like I did, in the solutions $c_n$ was calculated like $\dfrac{1}{2\,\pi}\displaystyle{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(t)\,e^{-i\,n\,t}}\,\mathrm{dt}$

Why is that possible the reason being $c_n$ actually is discontinuous at $t = \pi$?

Comment: Why not possible?  Finite sum is continuous, but convergence is not uniform.  At discontinuity it will converge to midpoint of limits.

Comment: I'm just puzzled, because the way $c_n$ is calculated gives a series, that converges to $\sinh(t)$ without including the discontinuity. Is it because it's just about one point that might be even negligible, not visible when you were to plot the graphs?

Comment: I am confused about your confusion.  The Fourier series will converge to sinh(t) for all t in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.  Calling it $0$ at one point doesn't effect the integrals to get $c_n$.  My previous comment was about functions with "natural" discontinuities, such as cot(x) at x=0.

Comment: Nevermind. I just had other piecewise functions in mind like $f(t)= \begin{cases}1,&-\pi<t<0 \\\\ 0,& 0 \leq t < \pi\end{cases}$ where you need to compute 2 integrals ($c_n = \int_{-\pi}^{0}\cdots + \int_{0}^{\pi}\cdots$). I thought the same principle would apply here but since the function just jumps at one point it's not worth mentioning.

Comment: But you mentioned an interesting point: If a function approaches a natural discontinuity, even a pole like $y = \cot(x)$ where $x$ goes to $0$ and $y$ to $\infty$: what's the average value between $y = \lim_{x \to 0}$ and, let's say, $0$ ?

Comment: I am not sure what happens in this case.  I was thinking about a finite jump.